# Perforce P4 copy without specific directory

Tags: copy, perforce

I have been dying to solve this problem... but I haven't been able to find a good answer yet.
I was wondering if any of you guys have a better idea for copying files over to other stream under my situation.

So here it goes.
currently, my tree somewhat looks like this.

```
//My_Depot/My_Stream/UE4/Client/...
//My_Depot/My_Stream/UE4/Client/Binaries/...
//My_Depot/My_Stream/UE4/Client/Config/...
//My_Depot/My_Stream/UE4/Client/Patches/...
//My_Depot/My_Stream/UE4/Client/Tools/...
//My_Depot/My_Stream/UE4/Server/...
//My_Depot/My_Stream/UE4/Admin/...
//My_Depot/My_Stream/UE4/Web/...
```

I want to be able to p4 copy all directories under UE4 (//My_Depot/My_Stream/UE4)
EXCEPT Patches (//My_Depot/My_Stream/UE4/Client/Patches/...) directory.
How do i go about doing this?
I need Patch directory during build and stuff so can't really exclude them from the view
(or can editing view done dynamically..?)

please helpp

I tried to google, I tried to stackoverflow. but no one really stumbled on my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.  Do you just want to do this just once?  Just open everything for copy and then revert the `Patches` directory before you submit:

```
p4 copy
p4 revert UE4/Client/Patches/...
```

Do you want to skip the `Patches` directory in your stream *every time* you do a merge or copy from the parent?  Then you want to `isolate` that path in your stream:

```
Stream: //My_Depot/My_Stream
Paths:
    share ...
    isolate UE4/Client/Patches/...
```

Do you want to isolate it in a particular workspace but not in every workspace of that stream?  See above, but make a separate `virtual` stream with the `isolate` line in it, and base your workspace on that stream.

Comment: thanks, the reason why i was asking the question was....
i'm already doing p4 copy then p4 revert to ignore specific directory, but the size of my revert directory is 300gb.... so the entire copy process is taking too long. So i was looking for ways to find shorten the time.
one question though.... if i make virtual stream to isolate certain path would that virtual stream take up space in perforce server?
I assumed when my stream is say... 100gb, then creating a virtual stream would take up 100gb (minus the isolated tree part?) on perforce server.
Am i correct?

Comment: No, for two reasons: first, a `virtual` stream doesn't branch the parent's files the way a normal stream does, it just maps the same files a different way (e.g. filtering some files out like you want to do here).  Second, branching a file doesn't result in a full copy of the file on the back end, just pointers (the pointers do take up some space, but it's a flat 1kb per file or so rather than duplicating each file in full).